# Which Map Projection to Use for Fantasy World Generator?

Tags: typescript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to write a program to generate a map of a world for an RPG I'm GMing. I'm wondering which map projection (or, to generalize it, how I should store information about the world) to use so that warping is minimized and distances are kept mostly the same. It looks like most of the simple map projections like the rectangle and square based ones have massive warping around the poles, which would make it difficult to make a good map for my purposes. However, the more accurate representation of the globe, the more difficult it would be to store it, as I see it. I would have to represent it with arrays of different lengths, which could be problematic.

I'm considering using a Sinusoidal projection, as that would be relatively easy to do and wouldn't involve insane warping.

Should I just use some kind of tiling that maps to a sphere, like the pattern on a Soccer Ball? That seems pretty easy to do, but I'm not sure, and I'm not sure if it would fit enough polygons to make high definition landscapes.

For reference, I'm using TypeScript with HTML5 Canvas technology.

Comment: If you're not asking about actual implementation details, just what map type to use, this would probably be better suited to eg. the worldbuilding/roleplaying sites, rather than SO.

Comment: Okay, that sounds reasonable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's off-topic

Comment: Sounds good. I asked the question on the World-Building SO, so I can delete this one if necessary.